# Spawn different, random colored DIVs for each list element

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, css, dom

I want to spawn three random colored div boxes behind each list element. I started with this, however it doesn't work - DIVs don't appear to be visible :(

http://jsfiddle.net/dgweu/1/

Help much appreciated!

HTML

```
<div id="wrapper">
    <ul>
        <li>li1</li>
        <li>li2</li>
        <li>li3</li>
    </ul>
</div>​
```

JS

```
$("li").each(function(){
    var randomColor = "#"+Math.floor(Math.random()*16777215).toString(16);
        for (var i = 0; i < 3; i++) {
            stripe = document.createElement('div');
            stripe.setAttribute('style', 'width:100px; height:3px; background-color' + randomColor);  
            wrapper = document.getElementById("wrapper");
            wrapper.appendChild(stripe);
        }
});
```

Answer (score 5, accepted):

The divs aren't visible because there's a syntax error in your CSS. You're missing a `:` after `background-color`.

To make the divs appear behind the `li`s, you could position the divs absolutely and the `li`s relatively.

Have a look at this [**DEMO**](http://jsfiddle.net/dgweu/20/). I've also tidied up your JS.

Comment: You removed the for statement, which is imperative to the desired result ("three random colored div boxes behind each list element"). Another note, the random color generation can yield invalid hex values.

Comment: move randomColor generation into the for loop and it'll be spot on.

Comment: Great, just what I needed, thanks! Meanwhile I came up with another solution, but it's messy and awful...

Answer (score 2):

You missed a colon in the javascript after the background-color element. [jsFiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/dgweu/2/)

`stripe.setAttribute('style', 'width:100px; height:3px; background-color:' + randomColor);`

Answer (score 2):

Your idea is correct, but you have a simple syntax error in your JavaScript.

```
stripe.setAttribute('style', 'width:100px; height:3px; background-color:' + randomColor);
```

You simply forgot the colon (`:`) after `background-color` in the `setAttribute()` function.

Answer (score 1):

You're missing a colon after your background-color

another thing, you said you wanted to insert the colored div behind each list element. you're script will just tack the elements at the end

I believe this is what you wanted
http://jsfiddle.net/dgweu/4/
Use jquery more often, it's incredibly convenient.
jQuery's insertbefore method makes everything easier
You create an element, query it, then insert it before each li element